# Install gnome-shell extension on command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, gnome, gnome-shell, shell-extensions

I'm looking for a way to *reliably* install gnome-shell extensions on the command line. At the end of the day, I'd like to have an Ansible playbook.

As an example, I'd like to install [custom-hot-corners-extended](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4167/custom-hot-corners-extended/).

I found ["Install GNOME extension using command line" on medium.com](https://medium.com/@ankurloriya/install-gnome-extension-using-command-line-736199be1cda) and also ["How to install Gnome Extensions on Ubuntu 20.04" on linuxhint.com](https://linuxhint.com/installing_gnome_extensions_ubuntu/). Following these, I did:

```sh
wget -O/tmp/extension.zip https://extensions.gnome.org/extension-data/custom-hot-corners-extendedG-dH.github.com.v11.shell-extension.zip
uuid=$(unzip -c /tmp/extension.zip metadata.json | grep uuid | cut -d \" -f4)
unzip /tmp/extension.zip -d "~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/$uuid"
gnome-shell-extension-tool -e "$uuid"
# or:
gnome-extensions enable "$uuid"
```

But it doesn't work - I get an error: **Extension »custom-hot-corners-extended@G-dH.github.com« does not exist**

It's (of course) also not shown in gnome-extensions-app. Manually installing the from the [GNOME Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4167/custom-hot-corners-extended/) site in the browser works just fine.

Also tried using the [gnome-shell-extension-installer script from brunelli](https://github.com/brunelli/gnome-shell-extension-installer) - also no go… :/

I'm using GNOME Shell 40.5 on Ubuntu 21.10 Impish.

Comment: Did you get this to work? I'd also love to be able to put installation in a script. I'm going to try this answer tomorrow: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617288/command-line-tool-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions

Comment: You have to use flatpak now  - https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu. And then https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.mattjakeman.ExtensionManager

Answer (score 1):

I've recently come across [gnome-extensions-cli](https://github.com/essembeh/gnome-extensions-cli), which seems to have been around for some time, but has only recently gained new activity (see [Code frequency](https://github.com/essembeh/gnome-extensions-cli/graphs/code-frequency) of the project). I think it's a great tool, it produces beautiful output, and it's also script-friendly. The CLI lets you search, install, upgrade, enable and list GNOME extensions, among other things.

If you don't mind installing a Python dependency on your target machine, you could write a couple of Ansible tasks to achieve your goal, like so:

```
- name: Install CLI tool to manage GNOME extensions
  ansible.builtin.pip:
    name: gnome-extensions-cli
    extra_args: --user --upgrade

- name: Install and enable GNOME extensions
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: gext install "gTile@vibou" gext enable "gTile@vibou"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install from a `.zip` file with:

```
gnome-extensions install ./custom-hot-corners-extendedG-dH.github.com.v11.shell-extension.zip
```

It may not work immediately after installation *(nor will the addon appear in the list of installed extensions of the extension app)*, which is clearly a bug someone needs to report. However, once you log out and log in back, it will start working.

The `gnome-shell-extension-tool` is obsoleted in preference of `gnome-extensions` utility.